# Find overlapping time between two timestamp in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, group-by

I have a table in postgers with schema similar to this.

```
id            start_time            end_time
1    2019-10-21 20:00:00 UTC    2019-10-21 23:00:00 UTC
2    2019-10-21 22:00:00 UTC    2019-10-22 02:00:00 UTC
```

I want to write a query which will give me overlapping duration in database itself.

for example: given two inputs
`t1=2019-10-21 21:00:00 UTC` 
`t2=2019-10-22 01:00:00 UTC`
the query should calculate all the  overlapping time between the input range

the overlapping time between input and row 1 is `2 hrs`
the overlapping time between input and row 2 is `3 hrs`
the result wold be 2 + 3 = 5

Comment: I don't understand why the overlap for the second row should be 4 hours. To me it's only three hours (from 22:00 to 01:00 next day)

Comment: yes it should be 3. editing the question. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds as if you are looking for the intersection of two [tsrange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) values:

```
tsrange(start_time, end_time, '[]') * tsrange('2019-10-21 21:00:00', '2019-10-22 01:00:00', '[]')
```

The `'[]'` specifies that both edges should be included in the range. This might or might not be what you want. You will need to adjust that to your requirements.

This will return a range type. To calculate the length of the range, subtract the upper value from the lower value:

```
select sum(upper(diff) - lower(diff))
from (
   select tsrange(start_time, end_time, '[]') * tsrange('2019-10-21 21:00:00', '2019-10-22 01:00:00', '[]') as diff
   from the_table
) t
```

This returns an [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) representing the sum of all overlap.

If your column is a `timestamp with time zone` you need to use `tstzrange` instead.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c06f664853e06f9c5f04df1ff131465b)

Comment: For like 10k rows, would it be best(in terms of performance) to have this calculation in database itself or in the app?

Answer (score 2):

You can use date arithmetics and aggregation:

```
select 
    sum(
        greatest(
            least(d.end_time, t.end_time) - greatest(d.start_time, t.start_time), 
            '0 hour'::interval
        )
    ) total_overlap
from mytable t
cross join (values 
    ('2019-10-21 21:00:00'::timestamp, '2019-10-22 01:00:00'::timestamp)
) d(start_time, end_time)
```

For each row, the difference between the smaller end time and the greatest start time gives you the duration of the overlap - if it is positive.